# Unable to read URL string from json and apply it to Object in Android

Tags: java, android, json, url

I'm building an application and have a `User` object:

```
public class User {
    private Integer id = null;
    private String username = null;
    private String password = null;
    private String first_name = null;
    private String last_name = null;
    private String email = null;
    private String phone = null;
    private String avatar = null;
    private String role = null;
    private Boolean confirmed = null;
    private Boolean active = null;
    private String created_at = null;
    private String updated_at = null;
    private String sex = null;
    private Object company = null;
}
```

This object(class) contains setters and getters.
When authorization response has come - i'm proccessing it with next callback:

```
public void onResponse(Call<ApiResponse> call, Response<ApiResponse> response) {
                ApiResponse apiResponse = response.body();

                Log.i("log_i", apiResponse.getData().toString());

                JsonReader jsonResponse = new JsonReader(new StringReader(apiResponse.getData().toString()));
                jsonResponse.setLenient(true);

                try {
                    User user = new Gson().fromJson(jsonResponse, User.class);
                    Log.i("log_i", user.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(context, apiResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("log_i", e.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to authorize in case of application exception.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
```

After it step to firt line after try{} - it's crashes and next error is apperas in Log:

```
I/log_i: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 147 path $.avatar
```

Logged JSON:

```
{
    id=4,
    username=admin,
    first_name=Test,
    last_name=User,
    email=test@email.com,
    phone=012.345.678,
    confirmed=true,
    active=true,
    avatar=https://path/to/avatar.png,
    role=admin,
    created_at=2017-02-24T14: 22: 50+00: 00,
    updated_at=null,
    company_id=2.0,
    sex=m,
    company={
        id=2.0,
        title=companyTitle,
        active=true,
        created_at=2017-02-24T14: 22: 50+00: 00,
        updated_at=null,
        deleted_at=2017-02-24T14: 22: 50+00: 00
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Cause i'm trying to solve this issue

**UPD 1**

On next line i'm getting error:

```
User user = new Gson().fromJson(jsonResponse, User.class);
```

Comment: I don't see where you define `context` in your `onResponse` in your try that you pass to `Toast.makeText` also can you specify which line is giving the error is it where Declare and set `jsonResponse`?

Comment: @user3299379, it's asyncTask. I'm passing Activity context into constructor.  I will upd question to highlight problem.

Comment: @user3299379, also Toasts working. There's np with them

Comment: can you try the following:
`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();`
`User user = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, User.class);`
to replace the line that is currently showing error

Comment: @user3299379, sure. Let me try.

Comment: @user3299379, still the same problem with `avatar` path

Comment: I should have caught this earlier, can you please show your java class for `Company` I think this is where the issue may lie

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139629/discussion-between-roman-kozin-and-user3299379).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem has been solved. My actions was next:
Instad of declaring:

```
User user = new Gson().fromJson(jsonResponse, User.class);
```

I should declare:

```
user = (User) apiUserResponse.getData();
// or
User user = (User) apiUserResponse.getData();
```

In other cases, Your JSON will be readed as malformed and exception will be thrown.